# Responsive: display: inline-block

Tags: html, responsive-design, css

I have two page sections, one on the left (my menu) and one on the right (my content). Now, they are both displayed as inline-block types, so that the content can be displayed to the right of them menu and then fall below the menu on smaller screens when required.

I was wondering, whether it is possible to make the content box resize responsively, until a minimum width, before it aligns under my menu?

Here is how my code is set out:

```
.menu {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 300px;
   vertical-align: top;
   background-color: #222;
}

.content {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 650px;
   vertical-align: top;
   background-color: #222;
}
```

Been stuck on this for around two hours now, had a look around and can't seem to find any similar questions here or online resources, can anyone shed some light on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: have you tried `min-width`?

Comment: @nullability yes, but as soon as the edge of the browser reaches the side of the content box it is aligned under the menu, it doesn't resize first before it moves.

Comment: Have you tried using media queries? Sounds like your solution to me.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with it, as I have only made basic responsive designs, I'm attempting to learn more but don't understand how to use it in this case, thanks for the replies.

Comment: Yes, Media queries are the only way (besides JS ofc). You should look at bootstrap's column system and their CSS (media queries). Don't try and invent the bicycle, just take what you need!

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, what you need is `@media` queries in your CSS. Assuming your elements are `div`, you can remove `display: inline-block;` and use `float`.

```
.menu {
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
   vertical-align: top;
   background-color: #aaa;
   /* margin-left: 50px; -- optional, for aligning to your needs */
}

.content {
   float: right;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 650px;
   vertical-align: top;
   background-color: #aaa;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) { /* width at which layout changes  */
  .content, .menu {
    float:none;
    position: static;
    /* width: 90px; -- set to the smaller value you want */  
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .menu {
    /* display: none; —- remove the menu, perhaps */
  }
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .content, .menu {
    /* more targetting -- usually margins and padding adjusting */
  }
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yCoit)

[CSS media queries on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

A few comments first.

Inline-blocks shrinkwrap around their contents, stretching horizontally as far as possible to incorporate their children.  If you have a text within an inline-block, the inline-block will stretch so that all of the text can be displayed in a single line.  If the latter behavior will make an inline-block stretch to the point that it, itself, cannot be in the same line with other inlines or inline-blocks, then it will be moved to a new line.

Explicitly setting `.menu`'s width is not a good practice.  Implicitly set the width by formatting the children of the `.menu`.  See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ueuh/.  You can adjust the width of the menu via font-size, padding-left, padding-right, etc. and make it grow dynamically.

That dynamic behavior that you are seeking can be accomplished by setting the element that contains the `.menu` and `.content` to be displayed as a table; and, the `.menu` and `.content` are displayed as table-cells.  This will keep the `.menu` and `.content` stacked horizontally.

HTML:

```
<div id = "#wrapper">
    <div class = "menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "content">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
            Duis auctor libero vel dignissim auctor. Vestibulum ac quam ut erat lacinia rhoncus ut non urna. Suspendisse ornare blandit orci, quis malesuada augue fermentum non. Nam feugiat, augue quis tristique blandit, lorem nunc faucibus elit, in tristique urna velit non nisi. Proin mauris eros, feugiat ac magna ut, aliquam dapibus neque. Integer lorem augue, condimentum non pellentesque a, facilisis ac mauris. Ut cursus elit justo, vel molestie lectus fermentum vitae. Etiam sed commodo orci. Aenean ullamcorper eros in orci pellentesque, sit amet dictum elit feugiat. Donec orci arcu, malesuada nec condimentum id, elementum at eros. Aenean pulvinar purus ac blandit dignissim. Curabitur condimentum augue vitae justo pharetra rhoncus. Nullam nisl arcu, feugiat a risus et, posuere varius erat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc eget lacus libero. Praesent blandit sollicitudin nisi eu posuere.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initial CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
    display: table;
}

.menu {
    display: table-cell;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px dotted #424242;
}

.menu ul li + li {
    border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.menu ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 12px/2 Sans-Serif;
    color: #151515;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu ul li:first-of-type > a {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.content > h2 {
    font: normal 24px/2 Sans-Serif;
}
```

And, the other folks are quite right.  To break the horizontal stacking of `.menu` and `.content` to vertical, you'll need some media queries.  This solution, however, requires only one media query to test if the available width is small enough to justify vertical stacking.

Media query CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .menu, .content {
        display: block;
    }

    .content {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menu ul {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu ul li {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

The media query portion of the code is complete in so far as it handles the transition from horizontal to vertical stacking.  I'll leave it up to you to finish the stylistic elements.

And, a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XZ3zq/.

Cheers.